# how to focus a button when a textbox is clicked

Tags: jquery, html

I have a textbox that when a user clicks inside it,it should put a focus on a button.I dont need to use an enter key press.i just want to focus on a button when a user clicks inside of a textbox.

```js
$("#txtBox").click(function() {

  alert("The textbox is clicked."); //added for testing purposes it doesnt get hit.
  $("#button").focus();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-sm-2">
  <label for="txtBox" class="sr-only">Text</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtBox" name="txtBox"></div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-1">
  <label for="button" class="sr-only">submit</label>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="button" name="button">Focus Me</button></div>
```

the problem is that my html is stored in a SQL script.so its not detecting `txtBox`

Comment: so you are getting the html dynamically (through aja or some other sort)?

Comment: I tried your code, it is running as expected. While clicking on the textbox it shows alert, then click on OK it changed focus to button.

Comment: Your code works fine.. see updated.

Comment: yeah i also tried it in a fiddle and it works,not sure why its not getting hit in my code

Comment: `the problem is that my html is stored in a SQL script.so its not detecting "txtBox"` explain more about this line.

Comment: the html is stored in sql, so using ajax to call it

Comment: this shouldn't matter.... html and JS run in the clients browser

Comment: @PhilippSander no , probably the matter is! think about it..

Comment: @pedram why should it matter where your HTML is coming from... If it's presented to the user it runs in the clients browser, that's it

Comment: @PhilippSander  check again `the html is stored in sql, so using ajax to call it`. so this is the matter! check my answer. // yes it's client side but the problem was, OP loaded html via ajax, after DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, according to *comments*, you load `html` via `ajax`, you append `html` after `DOM` so you need to use live *(bind)* function, you can use `.on` like this:

```js
$("#txtBox").on('click',function() {

  alert("The textbox is clicked."); //added for testing purposes it doesnt get hit.
  $("#button").focus();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-sm-2">
  <label for="txtBox" class="sr-only">Text</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtBox" name="txtBox"></div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-1">
  <label for="button" class="sr-only">submit</label>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="button" name="button">Focus Me</button></div>
```

**Or**

```js
$(document).on('click','#txtBox',function() {

  alert("The textbox is clicked."); //added for testing purposes it doesnt get hit.
  $("#button").focus();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-sm-2">
  <label for="txtBox" class="sr-only">Text</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtBox" name="txtBox"></div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-1">
  <label for="button" class="sr-only">submit</label>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="button" name="button">Focus Me</button></div>
```